# Problema de inserção de tabuada usando FOR

Tags: javascript, select, option

Tento fazer a option exibir a tabuada de 1 a 10 da var n1, mas ela só reconhece n1*10. Como fazer para ela exibir toda a tabuada (de 1 a 10)? Outra coisa que não consegui fazer é colocar um alert pra quando o dado inserido não for um número. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```js
function confirmar () {
  var n1 = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('num').value)
  var opt = document.getElementById('opção')
  var cp = document.getElementById('campo')
  opt.text = ""
  cp.add(opt)
  if (document.getElementById('num').value == "" || document.getElementById('num').value >= 1001) {
    alert('Deu ruim!')  
  } else { for(let i = 0;i <= 10;i++)  {
       var mult = n1*i
       opt.innerHTML = `${n1} x ${i} = ${mult}`
      } 
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Tabuada de Multiplicação</title>
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p>Insira um número:</p> <input type="text" name="numero" id="num"><br>  
    <select id="campo">
    <option id="opção"></option>
    </select>
    <br><input type="button" value="confirmar" onclick="confirmar()">
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Para que colocar a tabuada em um elemento `<option>`? Não sei o que está tentando fazer mas não seria menos estranho [criar](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) um `<option>` para cada linha da tabuada e o adicionar ao `<select>`?

Comment: Para viabilizar a pergunta no site queira seguir as [instruções já dadas quando perguntou da primeira vez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/540812/inserir-resultado-de-uma-tabuada-em-uma-option-dentro-de-uma-select-usando-for). Você pode restaurar a postagem e editar, que automaticamente ela vai para uma fila de reavaliação.